# Foreach loop randomly throwing “invalid argument supplied”

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I'm trying to get this function to work but for some reason it errors out on the foreach line saying there is an invalid argument.

```
$scores= TESTAPI::GUL($user->ID);
if (empty($scores)) {
    echo "<p>No Scores</p>";
} else {
    foreach ($scores as $score) {
        echo "<p>".$score."</p>";
    }
}
```

The error I get is: `PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

***Note: I need to keep the `if... else...` in the order it currently is.***

Some variations for the  if statement, prior to the for

```
if(!is_array($scores) && !count($scores) || empty($scores)){
if(!is_array($scores) && !count($scores)){
```

I can't use use `var_dump($scores);` because the error is on a page on a private website I run (can't provide links) and I am unable to find a way to recreate the error. Maybe someone knows a way I can capture data that causes the foreach to go wrong and save it to a log file?

Comment: $scores is not an array

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo but it clearly is 99% of the time because it runs fine normally and hence why I have thrown in `if(!is_array($scores)` in the variations.

Comment: what does TESTAPI::GUL($user->ID); return?

Comment: I think TESTAPI::GUL($user->ID) returns scalar value for single result and array for multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `error_log` in case it is no array:

```
$scores= TESTAPI::GUL($user->ID);
if (empty($scores)) {
    echo "<p>No Scores</p>";
} else {
    if(!is_array($scores)) {
        $scores_info = print_r($scores, true);
        error_log('$scores is no array but: ' . $scores_info);
        echo "<p>No Scores</p>";
    } else {
        foreach ($scores as $score) {
            echo "<p>".$score."</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

It will write to the error log. You can see more at [the error_log doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) how to configure it. You should clearly dry it up when you know what the error is, but for temporary catching it this works ...